# document.querySelector not working

Tags: javascript

can someone tell me what is wrong here,beacuse i tried everything,removing brackets/ading aditional,nothing works,i have working example of javascript,but it uses IDs instead of classes nad has only one reaction on condition,im writing all my code in Webstorm.

```
function show_privacy_selector(){
  if(document.querySelector(".privacy_selector").style.display == 'none'){
    document.querySelector(".privacy_selector").style.display = 'block';
    document.querySelector(".general_info").style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector(".security_selector").style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector(".name_change").style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector(".email_change").style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector(".password_change").style.display = 'none';}
else
    {privacy_selector.style.display = 'block';}}
```

Comment: What is `privacy_selector`?

Comment: its a class of a div,that toggles settings for privacy,like audience :D

Comment: does the `.privacy_selector` actually have `style="display:none"` or is it just hidden via the class CSS? if the latter then your if statement will return false.

Answer (score 1):

there is a syntax error in the last line. There are 2 curly brackets. Insert an opening curly bracket!

```
else
   { privacy_selector.style.display = 'block';}}
```